# save the pictures in the cache forever with Glide

Tags: android, caching, android-glide

I want to save the pictures in the cache as long as possible. You can suggest a code to do this process. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Glide uses memory and disk caching by default to avoid unnecessary network requests and offers methods to adapt the memory and disk cache behavior:

```
GlideApp  
.with(context)
  .load(//...)
  .skipMemoryCache(false)
  .into(imageView);
```

Glide will put all image resources into the memory cache by default. Thus, a specific call .skipMemoryCache( false ) is not necessary.if you deactivate memory caching, the request image will still be stored on the device's disk storage.

```
    val requestOptions = RequestOptions().diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
Glide.with(context).load(url).apply(requestOptions).into(imageView)
```

Comment: thank you for answer
i used this code 
is this code correct      
Glide.with(context)
                            .load(DataCoupon.get(position).getImage_product())
                            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.AUTOMATIC)
                            .into(holder.ImageProduct);

Comment: it could be right and depends on your strategy. please if if the answer is useful for you, accept and vote up the answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this but i am not sure

```
Glide.with(context)
                .load(constant.BASE_URL+"images/"+data.getPicture())
                .apply(new RequestOptions()
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .dontAnimate()
                .centerCrop()
                .dontTransform())
                .into(holder.imageView);
```

Comment: thank you for answer
i used this code 
is this code correct      
Glide.with(context)
                            .load(DataCoupon.get(position).getImage_product())
                            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.AUTOMATIC)
                            .into(holder.ImageProduct);

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible using `DiskCacheStrategy.RESOURCE` with `skipMemoryCache` set to `true`:

```
Glide.with(mContext)
        .load("Your Image Url")
        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESOURCE)
        .centerCrop()
        .placeholder(R.drawable.loading_indicator)
        .skipMemoryCache(true)
        .into(imgView);
```